# How to get cursor of ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

I use the most simpliest way in layout to define listview:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Since I need a checked list I use `CheckedTextView` in listitem template. The user can check as many items in list as he want. It's working fine.

I have a `ListActivity` root view:

```
public abstract class ActivityList extends ListActivity {
 protected ListView listView;
 public abstract void renderListView( String filter );
 @Override
 public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
  super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
  setContentView( R.layout.commonlist );
  listView = getListView();
 }
}
```

It is abstract, because `ActivitiList` will be the parent for other view classes, like  products, clients, etc. The *abstract renderlistview()* will be implemented by children with `SimpleCursorAdapter`, eg.:

```
public class ActivityProductList extends ActivityList {
 @Override
 public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
  super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
  ...
  renderListView( null );
 }
 @Override
 public void renderListView( String filter ) {
  listView.setChoiceMode( ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE );
  ...
  SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter( this, R.layout.productlistitemchecked, mCursor, from, to );
  setListAdapter( sca );
 }
}
```

The *ActivityProductList* is working fine.
The user does it all he want, then clicks on the FINISH button defined and implemented in parent class, where the listview is, too. His event handler is as follows:

```
protected void getCheckedItems() {
 try {
   String className = this.getListAdapter().getClass().getName();
   Log.e("NanCal", className);
   Class c = this.getListAdapter().getClass();
   ListAdapter la = this.getListAdapter();
   SimpleCursorAdapter ca = ( SimpleCursorAdapter )la;
   Cursor cursor = ca.getCursor();
   SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
   for( int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++ ) {
    int selectedPosition = selectedItems.keyAt( i );
    cursor.moveToPosition( selectedPosition );
    long rowId = ca.getItemId( selectedPosition );
    Log.d( "", "row id: " + rowId );
   }
  } catch( Exception exception ) {
   Log.e( "NanCalc", exception.getMessage() + "::" + exception.toString() );
  }
}
```

**The concept is: get the selected item's ids.**

However, in the line what I marked by comment the program crashes with error: 
[image: eclipse screenshot part]

The *this.getListAdapter()* gives me a `CursorAdapter` than the cast will crashes.

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: can you try to see what class it is (since apparently it is not SimpleCursorAdapter)?

Comment: you don't override setListAdapter?

Comment: no, I didn't override setListAdapter()

Comment: My conception is: _ActivityList_ (this) has _getListAdapter()_ method which gives _Listadapter_. Because the _ListActivity_'s listadapter was set by _SimpleCursorAdapter_, I use typecasting to _SimpleCursorAdapter_. After that the _adapter_ has _getCursor()_ method which gives the necessary _cursor_. Maybe it's wrong conception?

Comment: so, can you try to see what it actually is? where you cast it, can you log getListAdapter().getClass() before the exception?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. _getListAdapter().getClass()_ is actually a _SimpleCursorAdapter_. That's why I don't understand the fact. At the same time I have to cast it to retrieve the appropriate cursor.

Comment: can you add a log with the class name and post the logcat ?

Comment: of course Sir. I edited the issue with try-catch block and logger calls. The result is:

08-24 15:22:11.110 E/NanCalc  ( 3920): android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
08-24 15:22:11.110 E/NanCalc  ( 3920): android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter::java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: i don't see what's wrong here, but if you need the id of your items, you can consider getcheckedItemIds instead. edit : didn't see your target was 7, therefore this comment doesn't help

Comment: can you make sure in your imports that SimpleCursurAdapter is indeed the android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: Yes sir, the _import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;_ is the last one among my imports

Comment: that's really weird. can you test (la instanceof SimpleCursorAdapter) before casting it?

Comment: Yeah thats's weird, especially because the result is **false**!!

Comment: At least that makes sense. So, it is a SimpleCursorAdapter, but sometimes it is not? Since you only need the getCursor method, you can try to cast it to simply a CursorAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with sword...

I've tried to access the SimpleCursorAdapter from parent class (ActivityList). This way didn't work. Therefore I§ve changed the base class to abstract and add an abstract method which will return the selected row id's. The abstract method is implemented in child class (ActivityProductList).

I know this solution doesn't give mention to the original problem. But it works...

Thank you all responses.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why you are getting the issue without more information. You could debug your code and put a break point at the commented error line and just see what the adapter is a type of.

I would also suggested that since your method name is getCheckedItems(), simply use [getListView().getCheckedItemIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds%28%29) , just make sure you have set your choiceMode to either single or multiple.

Edit:
Since your approach doesn't really require a cursor, why not just use the listadapter that is returned? getListAdapter().[getItemId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29)() will return your id.

Comment: you have right, the code is more complex a little. Accordingly it I edited the issue. I tried the mentioned _getCheckedItemIds()_ but ListView has no such method. I'm newbie in android so it leads me into the forest if you understand me.

Comment: you need to target your api to 8. <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />, this will cover over 97% of android devices

Comment: I can's target the app to api 8 because it is mandatory to use api 7. BTW I tried the app under emulator running api 8 and the problem is still existing on it too.

Comment: Since the approach is to enable the user to select multiple rows therefore listView.setChoiceMode is set to  ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, I think I have to use cursor. getItemID() gets the row id associated with the specified position in the list, the only one which is selected.

Comment: i think several need to be checkable at once, therefore getItemId won't help (also, is give the selected item, not the checked one)